# What are the Closeness and shortest.paths functions definition in igraph package calculating?

Tags: r, igraph

I found a weird result in some data I am working on and decided to test closeness and shortest.paths functions with the following matrix.

```
test<-c(0,0.3,0.7,0.9,0.3,0,0,0,0.7,0,0,0.5,0.9,0,0.5,0)
test<-matrix(test,nrow=4)
colnames(test)<-c("A","B","C,","D")
rownames(test)<-c("A","B","C,","D")
test
    A   B   C   D
A 0.0 0.3 0.7 0.9
B 0.3 0.0 0.0 0.0
C 0.7 0.0 0.0 0.5
D 0.9 0.0 0.5 0.0

grafo=graph.adjacency(abs(test),mode="undirected",weighted=TRUE,diag=FALSE)
```

When I measure closeness() I get this:

```
> closeness(grafo)
        A         B         C         D 
0.5263158 0.4000000 0.4545455 0.3846154
```

Which is merely the sum of the weights and NOT the distancies (1-weights).

```
> 1/(0.7+(0.7+0.3)+0.5)
[1] 0.4545455
```

When I define distance as 1-weight, I get this

```
> 1/((1-0.7)+((1-0.7)+(1-0.3))+(1-0.5))
[1] 0.5555556
```

In the igraph manual, it says, in the formula, that it is the sum of distances. My question is, does the function actually consider the weight and, therefore, it is a bug, or WE should consider (and modify) our graphs' edges as distance to run this function?

The SAME issue occurs with the shortest.paths function btw. It gives me a sum of the weights, NOT distances.

```
> shortest.paths(grafo)
    A   B   C   D
A 0.0 0.3 0.7 0.9
B 0.3 0.0 1.0 1.2
C 0.7 1.0 0.0 0.5
D 0.9 1.2 0.5 0.0
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you get the definition `distance = 1-weight`? I'm pretty sure all these functions operate under the assumption `distance=weight`.

Comment: @josilber I got my adjacency matrix from a correlation coefficient. In the case, the higher the proximity of two nodes, the more correlated they are. However, using closeness in my graph with distance=weight would result in the contrary assumption. I understand that some graphs may use the weight as distance as a standard procedure. I asked because, in the cases that don't, this might be misleading, for there is reference to that in the manual.

Comment: Maybe check out the `?is.weighted` help page. But it's fairly common for the weight of the edge to be interpreted as the distance between nodes in the igraph library.

Comment: @MrFlick that was part of my question. I really don't know the extesion or diversity of the nature of data composing the edge weights. That's why I ask if weight=distancfe is a correct/common definition, or if it's wrong. Seems like I didn't know. But a note on this in the manual would help. Maybe even a field to manipulate this in the function...

Comment: Did you read the `?is.weighted` help page? It seemed to me to cover this: "Edge weights are used for different purposes by the different functions. E.g. shortest path functions use it as the cost of the path; community finding methods use it as the strength of the relationship between two vertices, etc. Check the manual pages of the functions working with weighted graphs for details."

Comment: @MrFlick you are right. It's there. Thanks. Sorry for the confusion